# How to export into excel from access with specific format

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have searched a lot but didn't find anything that can help me what I'm searching for it.

Actually I want that if i import excel file into access so then i run the query and export the data into excel file with specific format i just need suggestion that it is possible in Ms Access level.

I read this but not too much helpful for me [Formatting Excel file exported from Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985344/formatting-excel-file-exported-from-access)

for example I have a data in Ms.access like :

```
Member ID EmpID EmployeNames Relation DOB            SSN
11     1   AL-01  Jimmy       Emp     01/01/1900     0444
11     1   Al-04  Sheila      Spouse
11     1   Al-04  Jonny       Son
11     1   Al-04  Jone        Son
```

After Export Excel fields should be like this

```
GroupNo GroupName LName FName Relation Member Dob ...
                        Johny  Emp    
                        Sheila Spouse
                        JOhny  Son
                        jone   Son
```

Comment: Create a query in access with the desired output, right click, export. If I understand what you need.

Comment: Have you tried creating a query like `SELECT NULL AS GroupNo, NULL AS GroupName, NULL AS LName, FName, [Relation], ...` and then exporting that?